# Vertical lines on "li" items when Zoom changes

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am testing on Chrome. My button looks good without zoom.

[image: Without zoom]

```
<li class="active" id="site_content">
      <a href="#" id="site_content_link">Edit Content</a>
</li>
```

Here is how it looks if I zoom in/out

[image: With zoom]

Here is the CSS:

```
.sub_nav ul li.active, .sub_nav ul li:hover {
background: url("/assets/sub_nav_right.png") no-repeat scroll right 0;
padding: 0 11px 0 0;

.sub_nav ul li {
display: block;
float: left;
line-height: 16px;
margin: 0 0 0 28px;
}

.sub_nav ul li.active a, .sub_nav ul li:hover a {
background: url("/assets/sub_nav_left.png") no-repeat;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
padding: 5px 0 5px 11px;
text-shadow: none;
}

.sub_nav ul li a {
font-family: arial;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 16px;
}
```

I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BdGA4/

Comment: Is there a special reason you've chosen to use a background image to create pill-shaped button, rather than the `border-radius` property?

Comment: It is probably because of the background image gets cut of at the right side when the user zooms, could you please provide a link where we can test?

You can also achieve the same design without images using css3 (not Internet Explorer friendly but a fallback for IE could probably work well for you), please find more information here: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: could you create a jsFiddle, pls? I don't see where you're setting a background for the li's text.

Comment: Thanks, I will create a jsfiddle. Also I cannot change to css3 at this moment because I dont have enough time and it happens all over the site.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BdGA4/

Comment: Can you take a look at the fiddle? Thanks

Comment: I guess the problem is that your browser doesn't support half pixels. As example, a button width of 134px being zoomed at 105% gives 140.7px. Your browser rounds the pixels and fails.

Comment: It makes sense. Any workaround?

Comment: Use a different browser?  If the browser doesn't support half pixels, there's nothing you can do about it.  Either switch to using `border-radius` or live with it.

Comment: If you make the right side longer, then they would overlap right? That would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

best solution is to "slice" the sub_nav_left.png image as a 1px wide background image with horizontal (repeat-x) setting enabled. This would fill the space in all cases.

Comment: No, it breaks in other zoom levels, and in real size it is not ok, you see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've increased the size of the right side sprite. Instead of 11px in width it's now 16px in width. Both sprites now overlap so you won't see the zoom bug cause by browsers rounding pixels.

```
Fixed fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BdGA4/2/